# Firebase rules checking an existing resource data but returning permission denied

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

These firebase rules return permission denied when an authenticated user tries to create a post with two fields, an `authorId` field that contains the user's id(uid) and an `editStatus` field that contains `'published' | 'draft'`

```
   match /posts/{post} {
        allow read: if request.auth != null && resource.data.editStatus == 'published' 
            || request.auth.uid == resource.data.authorId;
        allow write: if  request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == resource.data.authorId;
      }
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you please share which Firebase version you use?

Comment: Please share a screenshot of a sample document too :D

Comment: Security rules on their own do nothing. Please edit your question to show the minimal, complete/standalone code that any of use can run to reproduce the problem against these rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating a new document, you cannot check the `resource.data.authorID` as at that point in time, the resource does not exist. Instead, you will want to look at the request's value from `request.resource.data.authorID`.

I also highly suggest breaking down your Security Rules into granular conditions to handle create vs update respectfully.

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations

Comment: Thanks so much Digi Byte -- yes, that was it!